# Why type constraint is not enough?

Tags: haskell

Looking for an explanation why following definition does not satisfy type inference:

```
-- | nub' - naive Data.List.nub implementation with extra constraint
nub' :: (Eq a, Show a) => [a] -> [a]
nub' = foldr (\e ac -> if e `elem` ac then ac else e:ac) []
main = do
    print $ nub' []
-- Error: No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘print’
-- The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
-- Note: there are several potential instances:
```

whereas adding `Integral` constraint makes the difference

```
nub' :: (Eq a, Show a, Integral a) => [a] -> [a]
nub' = foldr (\e ac -> if e `elem` ac then ac else e:ac) []
main = do
    print $ nub' []
-- outputs `[]'
```

Comment: You're defining `nub'` but calling `nub`.  Is it intentional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason adding an `Integral` constraint makes the code compile again is that the defaulting mechanism kicks in, because `Integral` is a subclass of `Num`, and that in turn makes the type variable `a` *defaultable* to `Integer`.

You can read the nitty-gritty in [the Haskell Report, section 4.3.4](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4), but the take-away message is that a `Num` (or subclass of it) constraint gives the compiler just enough information to make an informed guess what `a` should be.

Without the defaulting mechanism (you can try this by entering `default ()` as I just found out!), entering `42` in GHCi would give the exact same error message, and that's not very useful if you want to use GHCi as a fancy calculator...

Comment: That's it, thanks. *Default declarations*, learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not really with the type constraints on `nub'`. The problem is that the `[]` in `main` is an empty list; with no elements in it, GHC has know way of knowing which type of list it is, and thus which instance it should use to elements satisfy the constraints of `nub'` (or whether its elements don't in fact satisfy the constraints; the programmer could well have intended it to be a list of functions `[Double -> Double]`, which is certainly not in `Eq` or `Show`).

The empty list in the definition of `nub'` is fine because it's not used in isolation; it's passed to `foldr` along with other variables of known type (known to be specific variables constrained by class constraints, anyway). The type of `foldr`'s arguments then constrain that the empty list *has* to be the same type as the list that was passed in to `nub'`, and since we know that the input list's elements are in `Show` and `Eq` (since the compiler will not allow `nub'` to be called if it cannot prove this), then this must be true of the `[]` as well.

In main, you don't use the `[]` in a way that ties its type to any concrete type. In particular, in a larger program you'd be very likely to *use* the result of `nub' []` for further computation (not just printing), which would often tell the compiler what type it is. But here the compiler doesn't have much to go on; only that the type must be something that works with `print`, which basically just tells it that it must be some type in `Show`. That doesn't help, since we already knew that from `nub'`. We need to know *which* type it is, because instances can have different behaviour for each individual type (indeed, that's the whole point of type classes).

And in fact it does matter even in this simple case! `[Int]` (or almost any other type) will be shown as `[]`, but `[]` of type `[Char]` (remembering that `String` is just an alias for that) will be shown as `""`. Which `[]` did you mean? How is the compiler to know?

Adding the `Integral` constraint "fixed" the problem because now the compiler is trying to guess some type matching `(Eq a, Show a, Integral a)` with not enough information. Because the Haskell standard library is designed to use type classes to support numeric literals and basic arithmetic for multiple numeric types, this sort of "ambiguous type variable" error would show up almost all the time when working with numbers, and be very annoying. Since the standard numeric types are "approximations" of one another, we often **don't care** which one is used (so long as it supports the operations used in our code). So Haskell has a "defaulting" mechanism to arbitrarily pick a type that satisfies a *numeric* type class constraint (such as `Integral`, `Floating`, `Num`, etc). This only works when all the other constraints on the same type variable are other prelude classes (which `Eq` and `Show` are, so you're in luck here).

So basically, adding in the `Integral` constraint to `nub'` propogates this constraint to `[]` in `main`, and makes Haskell think that it now must be a list of some kind of `Integral` numbers, so it just defaults to `Integer`. This isn't actually doing anything to fix the underlying issue that there is an ambiguous type variable, it just trips over a feature that arbitrarily resolves certain very specific kinds of ambiguities.

To *actually* resolve this issue in a real program, a Haskell programmer would generally **say what they mean** and add a type declaration to the empty list: `print $ nub' ([] :: [Bool])` if you were considering it to be a list of Boolean values, for example.

Again, the issue is not at all in `nub'`, it's in `main`. Constraining `nub` with more and more type classes will not make the real issue in `main` go away, it just creates more cases of ambiguous type class use. Changing `nub'` to be one *particular* type, like `nubInt :: [Int] -> [Int]` would work; but then you're effectively statically declaring your `[]` to be of type `[Int]` by your choice of specialised nub variant, so why not skip the specialised nub definition and just statically declare `[] :: [Int]` directly, instead of doing it sideways through `nub'` with a lot more work?

In real code it's just not often a practical issue, since we don't spend all our time taking trying to `show` empty lists. If the list *or* the result of whatever function you're passing it to is used in any way that relates the element type to either a concrete type that meets all the constraints, or an input to the current function that already has the type constraints, then GHC has enough information to pick an instance without any additional input from you. This is an unfortunate class of error that comes up much more for beginners messing around with small code fragments than it does for experienced Haskellers writing code to actually do something; exactly the type of programmer who is least capable of understanding/fixing it.